# Awk: How to merge the contents of lines which has duplicate ID in first field

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file which has duplicate value in the first field. File has total of 4 fields. I want to merge the value of remaining 3 fields.

**Input File:**

```
123|abc123||GFD
234|xyz456|tsdrf34526|KLD
123||cdft091|GFD
123|abc123|cdft091|GFD
456|sdf872||LHG
```

**Desired Output:**

```
123|abc123|cdft091|GFD
234|xyz456|tsdrf34526|KLD
456|sdf872||LHG
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens if the values of the remaining fields are neither empty nor identical?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` program which seems to fill the urgent request...

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {FS = "|"; OFS="|"}
{
    a[$1]++
    f1[$1] = $2
    f2[$1] = $3
    f3[$1] = $4
}
END { for (i in a) print i, f1[i], f2[i], f3[i] }
```